# for loop goes infinite within the ready function

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        for (var i=0; i<20; i++) {
        document.write('hello world');
    }
    });
```

in this code for goes infinite. so what's the reason of that?

Comment: *-shrug-* Not for me. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/ZWjL9

Comment: it doesn't go to inifinite? it stops at 20? http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/bMyhf/

Comment: What do you mean 'goes infinite'? By inspection and testing, there's no infinite looping here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not go infinite,it prints 20 times only.

Comment: So I'm not sure what the heck is going on here. You ask why it runs infinitely, Srinivas says it doesn't, and then you mark him accepted and leave?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your document.write() is triggering another 'ready' event every time? Can you put an alert or something before the for loop to see if the ready function is being called repeatedly?